# Hibernate query not returning Zero value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Same query working in SQL

```
Select count(tbl_leads.lead_Status_Id) , tbl_LeadStatus.LeadStatus_Type FROM tbl_LeadStatus LEFT JOIN tbl_leads ON tbl_LeadStatus.LeadStatus_id = tbl_leads.lead_Status_Id GROUP BY tbl_LeadStatus.LeadStatus_Type;
```

Hibernate Query

```
Select s.LeadStatus_Type, count(l.status) FROM Status s "
                + "LEFT JOIN Lead l ON l.status = s.LeadStatus_id "
                + "GROUP BY s.LeadStatus_Type"
```

Expecting output is this

```
   Count  LeadStatus_Type
    '0'   'Cancelled' 
    '0'   'In-Progress' 
    '1'   'New' 
    '0'   'Sold' 
    '0'   'UnAssigned'
```

And HQL return this

```
'1', 'New'
```

Comment: is LeadStatus_type column is nullable? And if so, we expecting count on it from the hibernate explicitely?

Comment: '0', 'Cancelled'
'0', 'In-Progress'
'1', 'New'
'0', 'Sold'
'0', 'UnAssigned'
I need this and I get this 
1 "New"

because there is another count is null

Comment: Please elaborate the above '0', 'Cancelled' '0',...? And 'UnAssigned' is special marker value representing NULL; in that case you can use the coalesc function in HQL in select part as coalesc(s.LeadStatus_Type, 'UnAssigned')

Comment: Please show us sample data and your expected output.

Comment: I need the 0 count when no leads found to LeadStatus_id . it not showing that record in result

Comment: Expecting output is this 
0', 'Cancelled' '0', 'In-Progress' '1', 'New' '0', 'Sold' '0', 'UnAssigned'
And I get this 
'New' '1'
because other they don't find a single record associated with it

Answer (score 1):

Your join condition looks off.  In HQL we join from an entity to the other entity which exists as a property of the first entity.  Most importantly, there is no `ON` clause as that relationship is already known within Hibernate.  Try the following:

```
SELECT s.LeadStatus_Type, COUNT(l.status)
FROM Status s
LEFT JOIN s.LeadStatus_id l
GROUP BY s.LeadStatus_Type
```

Comment: Not working! Null pointer Exception and also you don't define l

Comment: @HarpreetSingh The query in your question is raw SQL, not HQL.  Are you looking for HQL or for raw SQL?

Comment: SQL query is running fine and give the desired output. I Need HQL query which returns 0 if count not found. The HQL query is also running but null value count not showing in it

Comment: Any Idea about this?

Comment: The query should be working.  Tell me the error and/or the error output.

Comment: i Know query is working 
'0', 'Cancelled' '0', 'In-Progress' '1', 'New' '0', 'Sold' '0', 'UnAssigned' 
I need this and I get this 1 "New" because there is another count is null